# Constructor issue : Actual and formal list differ in length

Tags: java

My problem is i have two classes, the first is implementation class which implements Runnable and the second one is interfaceView which extends frameview

but when i try to make an object of interfaceView in implement class 
e.g

```
interfaceview check1 ;
check1.get_sms_validation();
```

it gives me

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null application

exception

The code for implementation class is

but when i do

```
interfaceview check1 = new interfaceview () ;
  check1.get_sms_validation();
```

it tells me to make a constructor in the interfaceview  class and when i do that it give me an error

> Actual and formal list differ in length.

the code of my implementation class is

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package smsapp;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.smslib.GatewayException;
import org.smslib.TimeoutException;
import org.smslib.modem.*;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage;
import org.smslib.OutboundMessage;
import org.smslib.Service;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
/**
 *
 * @author ist
 */
public class Implementation implements Runnable {


    private boolean login;
    public static Service srv;
    public static OutboundMessage outMsg;
    public static String defaultPort="COM7";
    public static ArrayList<OutboundMessage> queuedMessages = new ArrayList<OutboundMessage>();
    static QueueSendingNotification queueSendingNotification = new QueueSendingNotification();
    private boolean phoneConnected;
    Thread t;
    String msg ="1";
    public String Data_For_File ;
    public  String messageFor_File = null;
    public int check = 0;
    Random generator;
    public String message;
    private SingleFrameApplication SingleFrameApplication;
   // private String messageFor_File1;
    public String messageFor_File1 = null;
//   public InterfaceView = new InterfaceView ();

    Implementation()
    {
        phoneConnected = false;
    }

    public boolean connectPhone(String comPort)
    {
        try
        {

            srv = new Service();
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("Modem 0", comPort, 9600, "", "");
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            gateway.setOutbound(true);
            gateway.setSimPin("0000");
            srv.addGateway(gateway);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Could Not connect to the Modem. Please try again.\n");

        }
        this.phoneConnected = true;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean startService()
    {
        try
        {
            if(phoneConnected)
            {
                srv.startService();
                t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
                generator  = new Random( 19580427 );
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             try
             {
                 System.out.println("Service Start Error ");
                 e.printStackTrace();
                 srv.stopService();
                 return false;
             }catch(Exception ee)
             {
                 System.out.println("Service Stop Error");
                 e.printStackTrace();
                return false;

             }
        }
        srv.setOutboundNotification(queueSendingNotification);
//        myTimer = new Timer (10000,runProcess);
//        myTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
//        myTimer.start();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean stopService()
    {
        try
        {
            srv.stopService();
            t.stop();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("There was an error in disconnecting.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true; 
    }

    public void run()
    {
       // processOutMessage("1");
      //  processOutMessage();

        while (true)
        {
//            System.out.println(alpha++);
            InterfaceView.statusMessageLabel.setText("Checking inbound messages");
            try {
                //            System.out.println("Checking inbound messages");
                            readMessages();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Implementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            InterfaceView.statusMessageLabel.setText("Processing messages");
//            System.out.println("Checking outbound messages");
        //    processMessages();
            InterfaceView.statusMessageLabel.setText("Checking outbound messages");
//            System.out.println("Checking outbound messages");
          //  sendMessages();
            InterfaceView.statusMessageLabel.setText("Waiting ... ");
            try {
                readMessages();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

                Logger.getLogger(Implementation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try
            {
                t.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println("Thread Pause Exception");}
        }
    }

    static class QueueSendingNotification implements org.smslib.IOutboundMessageNotification
    {

        public void process(String gtwId, OutboundMessage msg)
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("Sent Message from: " + gtwId + " , " + msg.getId());
                queuedMessages.remove(msg);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void readMessages() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        int check_Lenght = 0;

        if (srv.getServiceStatus() == Service.ServiceStatus.STARTED)
        {
            try{
                System.out.print ("\n\n\n\n\n" + "in the print block of above the interfaceview declaration");
                 InterfaceView check1 = new InterfaceView(SingleFrameApplication);
                InboundMessage msg = null;
                java.util.LinkedList<InboundMessage> list = new java.util.LinkedList<InboundMessage>();
                srv.readMessages(list, InboundMessage.MessageClasses.UNREAD);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                {

                    msg = list.get(i);

                    //TODO: submit the incoming messages to the database from this point. 
                    System.out.println("New incoming message from: " + msg.getOriginator() +" : \t" + msg.getText() + "\n");
                    saveSMS(msg.getOriginator(),msg.getText());
                    messageFor_File = msg.getText();

                    // Concatination of data
                    if (! messageFor_File.equals("Y"))     {           
                      Data_For_File = messageFor_File +  Data_For_File ;
                      check_Lenght = Data_For_File.length();
                     System.out.print("The Value for Data For File" + messageFor_File );

                          if (check_Lenght >= check){
                              System.out.println("\n\n\n" + "I am in x " );
                              DataPacketing call = new DataPacketing();
                              call.Write_To_File(Data_For_File);
                             }
                                 //put the message into database.
                               srv.deleteMessage(msg);

                    }
                    else 
                    {

                    messageFor_File1 = messageFor_File;
                    srv.deleteMessage(msg);
                    Read_Message_Notification ();



                    }
                }

            }

            catch(Exception e)

            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }

    }

    private void saveSMS(String originator, String text)
    {

        try
        {


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void processOutMessage(String sms)
    {
        try
        {
          // outMsg = new OutboundMessage ("03456305252", sms);
           // outMsg = new OutboundMessage ("03219409778", sms);
            outMsg = new OutboundMessage ("03456305252", sms);
            outMsg.setId("1");
            queuedMessages.add(outMsg);
            srv.queueMessage(outMsg);

            msg=msg+1;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

public String Read_Message_Notification () throws TimeoutException {

 // int check_Lenght;
 //String messageFor_File1 = "";



   System.out.println(messageFor_File1);

return   messageFor_File1;
}

}
```

And the code of my InterfaceView class is

```
/*
 * InterfaceView.java
 */

package smsapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import org.smslib.InboundMessage;
import org.smslib.TimeoutException;
import org.smslib.helper.*;


/**
 * The application's main frame.
 */

public class InterfaceView extends FrameView {



     private final String s = null;
    public String fileName;
    public String filePath;
    public float fileLength;
    public int No_Of_SMS;
    public String check = "N";
    public  DataPacketing [] Packets_Array  = null;
    public  DataPacketing start  = new DataPacketing ();
    public SingleFrameApplication app1 = new SingleFrameApplication ()
          {

       @Override
       protected void startup() {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
       }
   };


    private void customizations()
    {


    private void botton_startServiceMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                 
        if (!this.botton_startService.isEnabled())
            return;
        javax.swing.JInternalFrame j = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j ,
                    "Please wait while the service is being connected.",
                    "Starting Server!",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (instance.startService()) {
            j = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j ,
                    "Service Started Successfully.",
                    "Service Started",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            this.botton_startService.setEnabled(false);
            this.botton_connectPhone.setEnabled(false);
            this.botton_stopService.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            j = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j ,
                    "Service could not be started. Please connect the phone and try again.",
                    "Service Start Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            this.botton_connectPhone.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }                                                

    private void botton_connectPhoneMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                 
        if (!this.botton_connectPhone.isEnabled())
            return;
        if (!(instance.connectPhone(this.comPorts.getSelectedItem().toString()))) {
            javax.swing.JInternalFrame j = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(j ,
                    "Phone could not be connected. Please check the ports and try again.",
                    "Phone Connection Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        //this.botton_connectPhone.setEnabled(false);


    }                                                

    private void formPropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                    
        if (!(instance.connectPhone(instance.defaultPort) && (instance.startService())))
        {
            this.botton_connectPhone.setEnabled(true);
            this.botton_startService.setEnabled(true);
            this.botton_stopService.setEnabled(false);         

        }      

    }                                   

    private void SelectFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        fileName = f.getName();
        filePath = f.getPath();
        fileLength = f.length();
       // System.out.println("You have chosen: " + fileName+"\n from the path: "+filePath+"\n of the length: "+fileLength+" KB");         

        //------------------------------------- Calculating the Number Of SMS Required from the File Size

        float temp = fileLength/120;
        No_Of_SMS = (int) Math.ceil(temp);

        String SMS = " "+No_Of_SMS+" SMS";         
        SmsRequired.setText(SMS);
        String size2 = " "+fileLength+" KB";       
        FileName.setText(fileName);
        FileSize.setText(size2);

        this.FileName.setVisible(true);
        this.FileSize.setVisible(true);
        this.SmsRequired.setVisible(true);       
        this.jLabel3.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabel4.setVisible(true);
        this.jLabel6.setVisible(true);
        DataPackets.setText(" InterKnot:\\"+filePath);

        try {
            Packets_Array  =   start.Driver(fileName,filePath,fileLength,No_Of_SMS);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfaceView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
        this.DataPackets.setVisible(true);

      //  DataPacketing setFile = new DataPacketing();
      //setFile.File_Name_Path(fileName, filePath);


}                                          

    private void FileNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

    private void FileNameKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

    private void ReadandSendFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:

     //  DataPacketing [] Packets_Array  = null;
      // DataPacketing start  = new DataPacketing ();
         System.out.println("I am not yet in if");
        String s = null; 
         if(check.equals("N")){
        System.out.println("Do i Come here ????");
             try {
        //InboundMessage userNo = null;
            //String info = "User: " +  "wants to share file :"+ FileName+ " of size: "+FileSize+ "with you.To allow Reply Y";
                 String newInfo = "User Wants to share a file with you. To allow reply Y";
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n" + newInfo);
                message1.processOutMessage(newInfo);

                         System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "I am In try to check for the read notification message");

                          }catch (Throwable t) {
                               System.out.println("The Exception" + t);

                  }

             Implementation check1 = new Implementation ();
            try {


                check = check1.Read_Message_Notification();


            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {

                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfaceView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }



        if (check.equals("Y")){


        //  --------------------------------------------converting String Array into String


        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        //  -------------------------------------------- LOOP to send WHOLE file 

        for(int i=0; i<Packets_Array.length; i++)
        { 

                String s1 = Packets_Array[i].Data_Segment;
                System.out.println(s1);
                message1.processOutMessage(s1);
        }                

        //  -------------------------------------------- To send First Packet of file

        }


         }


        else
        {

        System.out.println("The User Refused to Allow the Transfer");

        }
    }                                               

    private void FileSizeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void FileSizeKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                   

    private void SmsRequiredActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void SmsRequiredKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    private void DataPacketsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void DataPacketsKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField DataPackets;
    private javax.swing.JTextField FileName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField FileSize;
    private javax.swing.JLabel PicGlobe;
    private javax.swing.JButton ReadandSendFile;
    private javax.swing.JButton SelectFile;
    private javax.swing.JTextField SmsRequired;
    private javax.swing.JButton botton_connectPhone;
    private javax.swing.JButton botton_startService;
    private javax.swing.JButton botton_stopService;
    public static javax.swing.JComboBox comPorts;
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel5;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel tab_settings;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    Object table_keywords_columns[] = { "Keyword",  "Reply Text"};
    Object table_outgoingSMS_columns[] = { "Number",  "Text", "Time"};
    Object table_incomingSMS_columns[] = { "Number",  "Text", "Time", "Auto-Reply Keyword"};
    private final Timer messageTimer;
    private final Timer busyIconTimer;
    private final Icon idleIcon;
    private final Icon[] busyIcons = new Icon[15];
    private int busyIconIndex = 0;
    private Implementation instance; 
    private JDialog aboutBox;
    public Implementation message1 = new Implementation();
    JProgressBar progressBar;

   void messagecheck(){
   System.out.print ("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + "I am in the message code of the interfaceview class");



   }


}
```

What to do ?

Comment: Can you show us your classes?

Comment: @Nick i have added the code of both my classes in the question again.

Comment: Where in the code do you get the NullPointerException? Where do you call `check1.get_sms_validation();` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example fails because you haven't assigned anything to the variable, so it's `null` and you get a `NullPointerException`.

Your second example fails because the constructor function expects arguments and you're not supplying them. You need to look at the `interfaceview` class's constructors and provide the relevant arguments.

For example, if `interfaceview`'s only constructor looked like this:

```
public interfaceview(String foo) {
   // ...
}
```

...then to create it, you'd have to supply a `String`:

```
interfaceview check1 = new interfaceview("Some string here");
```

---

I think it would probably be useful to take a step back and work through some Java tutorials (there's no shortage of them out there). Also, just for what it's worth, normally in Java interfaces and classes are written in initially-capped camelCase, e.g. `InterfaceView` rather than `interfaceview`. You can ignore that convention if you like, but following it makes code much clearer to others.

Comment: i did but now it gives me the exception 

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null application
 at org.jdesktop.application.View.<init>(View.java:79)
 at org.jdesktop.application.FrameView.<init>(FrameView.java:23)

Answer (score 0):

The first error cause by `check1` is not initialized, so you got a null point error. 
The second error cause by interface cannot be `new` in jave, you need have a normal call implement the interface.

Comment: Is `interfaceview` a interface class? Java does not allow to create a instance from a Interface class.

Comment: you call `InterfaceView check1 = new InterfaceView(SingleFrameApplication);` to create a instance, but you do not have this consructor in your `InterfaceView` class.

Comment: i know that. The problem is when i try to make that constructor it does not let me do it 

it give me this error 

constructor FrameView in class org.jdesktop.application.FrameView cannot be applied to given types;
  required: org.jdesktop.application.Application
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: the error is very clear, `FrameView`'s constructor need an `Application`, but in your `InterfaceView`'s constructor, you pass it a `SingleFrameApplication`, so `FrameView`'s initialization is failed.

Comment: i am sorry i am really bad at it. i didn't get what u mean by application here.

Comment: Please show me the `InterfaceView`'s constructor that you try to make. I guess inside the constructor you need call `FrameView`'s constructor which need a parameter with type of `org.jdesktop.application.Application`

Comment: @ user1335794 the calling from implementation form is 

   InterfaceView check12 = new InterfaceView ();

and the constructor  


    InterfaceView() {
        
        string s = "y" ;
        check = y;
    }

Comment: Have you checked whether `FrameView` provided a default constructor? From above error shows `FrameView` only provided a constructor like this `FrameView(org.jdesktop.application.Application)`.

Comment: i checked it out and it seems framview only provides **FrameView(Application application)** this constructor. So there is no way to make a object of InterfaceView class in implementation class to use its function.?

Comment: yes, that correct, since your `InterfaceView` extends from `FrameView`, so inside `InterfaceView`'s constructor you need initialize `FramView`.

Comment: oh ok, by the way any idea how to go about it ? and thanks a lot :)

Comment: Personally, I would suggest your change your `InterfaceView`'s constructor into `InterfaceView(Application application)`, so you can use this `application` to initialize its parent.

Comment: i did try that too. i didn't work it says 
**
 at org.jdesktop.application.View.<init>(View.java:79)
 at org.jdesktop.application.FrameView.<init>(FrameView.java:23)** :(

Comment: you need check the usage of `org.jdesktop.application` package. The initialization of `FrameView` is failed.

Answer (score 0):

> interfaceview check1 ;
>   check1.get_sms_validation();

Will give you a NullPointerException because it hasn't been initialized.

> interfaceview check1 = new interfaceview () ;
>     check1.get_sms_validation(); 
>   it tells me to make a constructor

More likely there is a constructor which is already there which you are not using.

> Actual and formal list differ in length.

You are not using the constructor you think you are.

Comment: i am using the one i made because the other constructor is taking one argument.

Comment: This means you have to give it one argument when you call it.

Comment: even if i give it one argument it still give me the null error !!